# Funny but unreadable bookmarks with backslash in section

Tags: hyperref, luatex, bookmarks

The following document gives me a "good" document, but garbled bookmarks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
tex.sprint("\\section{")
tex.sprint(-2,"Hellö \\wörld")
tex.sprint("}")
\end{luacode*}
foo bar baz
\end{document}
```

This is the document:

[image]

And this is what the bookmark looks like:

[image]

What can I do to get "correct" bookmarks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The escape character is also used for escape sequences in PDF strings. A naked backslash confuses `hyperref`, because it does not know, whether it is a printed backslash or the start of a PDF escape sequence.

To make it clear, use `\textbackslash`. But this will not work either, because of the wrong catcodes (`tex.sprint(-2, ...)`). Therefore `\textbackslash` cannot be parsed as macro.

The next step is using the internal representation of `\textbackslash` (see `puenc.def`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
tex.sprint("\\section{\\texorpdfstring{")
tex.sprint(-2,"Hellö \\wörld")
tex.sprint("}{")
tex.sprint(-2,"Hellö \\80\\134wörld")
tex.sprint("}}")
\end{luacode*}
foo bar baz
\end{document}
```

(I have added package `bookmark`, because it updates the bookmarks faster.)

Comment: I hoped to go completely without parsing the input (the string containing the backslash), as it can be "anything". Is there an algorithmic way (i.e. a standard encoding) for the characters? That way I could sanitize my input.

Comment: @dıʞsdoʇ An algorithm would be to convert the input string to UTF-16BE, then to convert the bytes to octal notation and to prefix the first byte with `\9` and the second byte with a backslash. For example, `\9000\134` would be the backslash. `\8` is only an abbreviation for `\900`.

Comment: The algorithm works fine for all my test cases, and I try hard to to outsmart it :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but I think you might need to replace `\\wörld` with `\\\\wörld`. Reasoning:

- `\\wörld` in Lua converts to
- `\wörld` in LaTeX, which converts to
- whatever the `\w` macro does.

But

- `\\\\wörld` in Lua converts to
- `\\wörld` in LaTeX, which converts to
- backslash followed by 'wörld'.

Comment: `\\\\wörld` makes the section entry incorrect.